# Get random enum from a select group

Tags: c#, random, enums

Given a group of about 20 enums that I cannot modify.

Im looking for an elegant solution to generate a random enum from a specific sample (ie, 2, 7, 18)

I could put these into an arraylist, but thought I would ask if there is something else I could try.

Comment: What do you mean by "a group of about 20 enums". Do you mean an enumeration with 20 enumerators? Can you post a code sample?

Answer (score 5):

If your values are all of the same type:

```
MyEnum[] values = { MyEnum.Value2, MyEnum.Value7, MyEnum.Value18 };
Random random = new Random();
MyEnum randomValue = values[random.Next(values.Length)];
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get all the values for a given enum type with:

```
var values = Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum));
```

Answer (score 1):

I knocked up a quick console app that does something like this, can't attest to how performant it is though :)

```
using System;

namespace RandomEnum
{
    class Program
    {
        private enum TestEnum
        {
            One, Two, Three, Four, Five, Six, Seven, Eight, Nine, Ten
        };

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] names = Enum.GetNames(typeof (TestEnum));

            Random random = new Random();

            int randomEnum = random.Next(names.Length);

            var ret = Enum.Parse(typeof (TestEnum), names[randomEnum]);

            Console.WriteLine(ret.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do it so complicated...

```
private static T GetRandomEnum<T>()
{
    return Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)).Cast<T>().OrderBy(e => Guid.NewGuid()).First();
}
```

Usage:

```
GetRandomEnum<MyEnumType>()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    enum days
    {
        sunday,monday,tuesday,wednesday,thursday,friday,saturday
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        Console.WriteLine(Enum.GetNames(typeof(days))[r.Next(1, 7)]);    
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, an explanation is needed to make it to an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to put those enums you want to choose from into an array or list of some kind and randomly pick from that.

If you just randomly pick from the the full definition you'll have to check the answer and reject those you don't want.